# Как разбить по недостающим дням датафрейм и заполнить 0?

Tags: python

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A9UDhi9cCHiuzlmyiPanmqICP_A921QU
По данным не могу сделать resample по дням; при resample появляются несуществующие даты до декабря 2020 года. Как заполнить новые дни 0?

```
df_ = df.resample('D').mean();
df2 = df_['2017-04-05':'2020-01-30']
```

Когда я делаю так, то нужные реальные данные заменяются средними, а мне надо, чтобы заменялись только null на 0.

Comment: Во-первых, мы не знаем, как вы там делаете resample. Во-вторых, что значит "resample по дням" если ваши данные и так заданы "по дням".  В-третьих, что значит "разбить (? - ведь resample  != разбить)  по НЕДОСТАЮЩИМ дням"? Наконец, как вы собираетесь примерно 330 дней до декабря 2020 заполнять скользящими средними за 30 дней? В общем, какая-то непонятная смесь терминов, слабо связанных между собой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял из документации по Pandas, можно сделать так:

```
df.resample('D').asfreq().fillna(0)
```

asfreq() - взять получившиеся после ресемпла данные "как есть" (не заполнять промежутки)

fillna(0) - заменить везде NA на указанное значение (в данном случае 0)

Comment: Ошибка ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @svil Дома посмотрю что у вас за данные, сейчас не могу в гугль драйве посмотреть

Comment: Там дубликаты Период  нельзя удалять, по ним нужно сложить значения по столбцам 'КоличествоОборот', 'КоличествоКонечныйОстаток','СуммаОборот',